# Firestore write security rule for specific user using auth names

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

New to Firestore security rules and is trying to understand it. I'm trying to write a security rule that allow only `admins` in my collection to write data and every one to read it.

The collection of `admins` has document ids as admin names, that is for example, "Mary Lane". Within the documents I've fields:

```
email: "userMailId@mail.com"
uId: "firestore_user_Id"
```

The `uId` is the id of Firestore user id. The data to write is an object `Message` and is:

```
new Message(uId, title, messageBody, timestamp)
```

Currently I'm trying to match the `request.auth.uid` with the id of the `admins` that are stored within the collection:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uId;
    }
  }
}
```

Is this is write or am I doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific about what you mean by "I have the collection of admins and document ids as admin names".  If these "admin names" are not part of Firebase auth user data, you won't be able to accomplish your task.  Optimally, you want your admin data index by firebase auth uid.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've edited the question. Is it ok now?

Comment: You haven't clarified how you are identifying admins in your admin collection.  What's the document id?  If the document ID isn't a Firebase auth UID, then this is probably not going to work.

Comment: @DougStevenson edited the question again. I'm using document id as the name of the person.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the admin's name is not available in this rule `allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uId;`, there is no way to look up the document to check it they're an admin.

You'll need a collection where you keep a document for each admin with their UID as the document key/name. Once you have that, you can check for the existence of such a document in the rule with:

```
allow write: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/admins/$(request.auth.uid));
```

Also see the [documentation on accessing other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).

Comment: Thank you. After lot of searching the docs I also figured it out yesterday but got so busy fiddling with it, forgot to give an update. But as I wanted to use a name, the last path for me is `admins/$(request.auth.token.name))`. Thanks again.

Comment: I didn't know there's a `name` property in the token. Is that the `displayName` of the user? Or is it a custom claim?

Comment: You seriously asking me?! :p Correct me if I'm wrong, it's the display name from the auth. However, I'm yet to test it thoroughly.

Comment: I looked it up [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth) and it's indeed the user's display name: "**name** - The user's display name, if set."

Comment: Really helpful features. This is the sweetness of firebase, where you can't get some features directly but indirectly you can achieve what you want. Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen